# Error: Connection to db:5432 refused - Persistent Issue Connecting Ktor Application to PostgreSQL in Docker Containers

Tags: docker, kotlin, jdbc, docker-compose, ktor

I'm encountering the `"Connection to db:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections."` error while connecting a Ktor application to a PostgreSQL database using Docker containers.

The Docker Compose and JDBC seems properly configured. I've checked the PostgreSQL container's execution and console says that the container of database is UP (the container of the app/api is not up, once it crashes when could not to connect). The error persists and additionally, it's important to note that I consistently rebuild and generate a new `fatJar` of the project (via the gradle wrapper, as usual) before running the Docker stuff.

Below are my relevant Docker and main class of the study:

- File used to create the docker image of my kotlin project:

```
FROM openjdk:17
LABEL authors="Francisco Lucas"
RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./build/libs/EstudoDocker-0.0.1.jar /app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

- My `docker-compose.yml` definitions:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: estudodocker
    container_name: estudodocker-postgres-container
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - estudo

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: estudodocker-image
    container_name: estudodocker-container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - estudo

networks:
  estudo:
```

I even tried to keep some declaration names in portuguese to help me locate and type then.

- My `Main.kt` class, entrypoint of my Kotlin api:

```kotlin
// just to illustrate the process
object NamesTable : IntIdTable() {
  val name = text("name")
}

// tried to put all the code inside main, to help understand the setup flow
// also, even taking the enviromnent variables from `System.getenv()` or
// hardcoded it doesn't works...
fun main() {
  val dataSource = HikariDataSource(HikariConfig().apply {
    // also tried to declare the URL with and without the port number
    this.jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/estudodocker"
    this.driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    this.username = "postgres"
    this.password = "postgres"
    maximumPoolSize = 3
    isAutoCommit = false
    transactionIsolation = "TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ"
    validate()
  })

  val db = Database.connect(dataSource)

  transaction(db) {
    // also tested with "create missing tables"
    SchemaUtils.create(NamesTable)
  }

  embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0", module = Application::module).start(wait = true)
}

fun Application.module() {
  configureSerialization()
  configureRouting()
}
```

- Relevant error log of the app/api container crash:

```
estudodocker-container           | 2023-12-27 02:32:46.539 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
estudodocker-container           | 2023-12-27 02:32:46.583 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to create/setup connection: Connection to db:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
estudodocker-container           | 2023-12-27 02:32:46.583 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source
estudodocker-container           | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to db:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I am not able to find the problem once, basically, in all the links I search instructions to this the setup is very similar with the above. So, how can I fix that? The problem is in the docker, in the kotlin project or both?

**EDIT:**
I randomly added a call to `delay(10_000L)` in beggining of `main()` function and "magically" the error was gone. The conclusion could be that, for some reason, the app/api was trying to connect to database before the database itself is UP...

Based on this: why is this happaning? There's another way to fix that without that *macgyverism* of `delay()` function call?

Comment: `depends_on` only waits for the database container to be started. It doesn't wait for it to be ready to accept connections. So if you try to connect as soon as your app starts, you'll often see this error. Some databases have a healthcheck so you can wait for the container to be healthy, but AFAIK, Postgres doesn't. My best advice is to add some resiliency to your code, so you can handle that the database isn't always available.